# How to add entry for a new kernel in the bootloader config file?

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, linux-kernel, grub, boot-loader

I am using Manjaro Linux. For a project, I had to reconfigure a new kernel and compile it. I used this guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel/Traditional_compilation . 
I am done all steps but the last one, which is, configuring it to the bootloader. I have no idea how, I tried looking online and such, but didn't find a satisfying answer, probably because I am not knowledgeable. I know I have grub, but not sure which one - at least not grub-legacy that's for sure. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Anyone looking at this, after all the steps in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel/Traditional_compilation , all you need to do is `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` if you are using grub as your bootloader. 
As easy as that!